# AWS4 Signature in GoLang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, signature

I started programming again recently and would need some help as I've been bashing my head against the keyboard for some days now but the code coming out doesn't seem to do the trick... The scope of my project is simple; send API requests to a server that uses AWS authentication
I've implemented the below to create the signature:

```
    authString := "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=**AWS Access**/"
    authString += time.Now().Format("20060102" /*T150405Z"*/) + "/"
    authString += "eu-west-1/"
    authString += "execute-api/"
    authString += "aws4_request,"
    authString += "SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date"

    awsSecret := "**tis a secret**"

    /*
        Pseudocode from documentation

           kSecret = your secret access key
           kDate = HMAC("AWS4" + kSecret, Date)
           kRegion = HMAC(kDate, Region)
           kService = HMAC(kRegion, Service)
           kSigning = HMAC(kService, "aws4_request")
    */

    hash := getHMAC([]byte("AWS4"+awsSecret), []byte(time.Now().Format("20060102")))
    hash = getHMAC(hash, []byte("eu-west-1"))
    hash = getHMAC(hash, []byte("execute-api"))
    hash = getHMAC(hash, []byte("aws4_request"))

    authString += ", Signature=" + hex.EncodeToString(hash)

    return authString
}

func getHMAC(key []byte, data []byte) []byte {
    hash := hmac.New(sha256.New, key)
    hash.Write(data)
    return hash.Sum(nil)
}
```

Signature string

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=**AWS Access**/20200421/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=7b0fe4780c1c5ba39d0dee1774135d81c0bcca85f5e83325299c245eba1b0e5e
```

Response

```
{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your 
AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'POST\n/prd/config/\n\ncontent-type:application/json\nhost:1294t77jvc.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-content-sha256:\nx-amz-date:2020-04-21T10:33:36+01:00\n\ncontent-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date\n3cffc0f4da0132a4156d5c1a6506b4b163368ee9b131dce71e8316bd2220650b'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20200421T093336Z\n20200421/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_request\n3e40376452b02b8ba7f2826971e0438fd6891ccbf4c94e553dd91a2cc6f68560'\n"}
```

Bear in mind the response is with some bogus data, but it's pretty much the same as if it had the real AWS Access and secret keys. Feel free to criticise anything you see up there, as I'm trying to get good practices as well

Regards,

Comment: Verify that the canonical string computed by your application matches the one given in the error message.

Comment: I know I'm getting the canonical string wrong, but I'm not sure if it's because of the signature being wrongly calculated or because I'm not passing enough/correct parameters on the header; 1. I'm getting the JSON request body in correctly; 2. Then I create the request **http.NewRequest("POST", endpoint, JSON-body)**; 3. Add headers such as content type and the x-amz-date... What I did is get a request that worked fine from software that actually works (RAW request) and try to mimic the parameters passed on that one... As to how to check the exact canonical string on Go, that's another battle

Comment: The code in the question uses the signing key as the signature.  Use the signing key to sign data. Follow the steps at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-string-to-sign.html.

Comment: Are you able to solve this @MannyCalavera? Having the same problem now.

Comment: Afraid not @san
This was going to be a quick script but I ended up going with a more mature language. I don't discard going back to golang, but for now I'll stay with python and java

Answer (score 1):

I somehow manage to successfully solved it based on your scripts. You're missing the string_to_sign with this pattern

```
stringToSign := algorithm + "\n" + amzDate + "\n" + credentialScope + "\n" + hash(canonicalRequest)
```

and it should be included in the signature. So you have to like

```
signatureWithStringToSign := GetHMAC(hash, []byte(stringToSign))  
authString += ", Signature=" + hex.EncodeToString(signatureWithStringToSign)
```

Comment: hope it helps to anyone who's struggling to it.